# How to clone a worktree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

If there is a remote repository with multiple worktrees, and I am trying to pull one worktree from them. How can I do that? Is a normal clone enough?

Comment: The worktree must be working on top of a branch (or something) from the main repo so cloning the main repo (or the specific branch if you know it) should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *no*.[1]

A `git clone` will get you a repository and won’t give you any choice on
what “worktree” to get.[2] But what if the remote had ten worktrees?

But does that even matter to git-clone(1)?

Let’s consider what a worktree is. Each has:[3]

1. A working tree (the tree belonging to `HEAD`)

   - This is what is checked out in your directory tree. For example if
     you created a repository with just a file named `README.md` then
     that will be all.
2. The repository metadata which is *not* shared between all the worktrees:[4]

   - Presently only `HEAD` and `refs/bisect/*`[5]

But what does that have to do with cloning the repository? Presumably
you just want to get some refs (like branches and tags) from the remote
that you are cloning.

Maybe you care about the `HEAD` of the remote, i.e. what branch it is
pointing at? But if you care enough about the worktrees of the remote
then you might already now what branch you want (presumably the one
checked out in the worktree). So just fetch that one directly.

#### Notes

1. Some research I did:

   1. `man git-clone`[2] says nothing apparently relevant about worktrees
   2. `git version 2.40.0`
   3. `man gitglossary` says nothing that makes me think that worktrees
      are relevant in this context
2. This repository will have one worktree (the “main” one) but that
   seems irrelevant here
3. `man git-glossary`
4. `man git-glossary`, “per-worktree ref”
5. (again) `git version 2.40.0`